# How to Print the data set in controller from controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

Can I print the data I set in controller from controller?

Ie:

if I have

```
$this->set("name", $this->data['student']);
```

So I want to know how to print value of name from within the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what's stored in the controller via:

```
pr($this);
```

The vars set via $this->set() are stored in

```
$this->viewVars
```

So in your case,

```
$this->viewVars['name']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can print a variable inside the controller, but it is not a good way to do this because you will break the MVC pattern.

Using the `echo` you can print a string and using `pr` you can print an array, object  or any other data type.

Inside your Controller, use:

```
echo $this->data['student']; // as soon as $this->data['student'] is a string.
```

or

```
pr($this->data); // as soon as $this->data is an array.
```

Instead of breaking the MVC, set the variable to the View, and access them using the name of the variable as you setted before:

In Controller, use:

```
$this->set("name", $this->data['student']);
```

In View:

```
echo $name;
```

Comment: Thanks fZmaster. I completely agree with you in regards to breaking the MVC patter. I am newbie and I was trying to debug something. Costa's solution worked like a charm. 
Thanks a lot both of you.